# spring batch rowNum does not increase

Tags: java, spring-batch, mapper, late-binding, rownum

I have a Spring batch job to get few rows of data from database to do something.

I wish to do something in first row in `RowMapper`.

```
public myVO mapRow(ResultSet rs, int rowNum) throws SQLException {
    System.out.println("rowNum is " + rowNum);
    if (rowNum == 1) {
        // do something
    }
    // some other code here
}
```

This is working fine for me at first. However, after I add in `scope="step"` in my batch xml file at reader part, the `rowNum` will always 0 instead start of 0 and increase.

Any way to fix this while I wan to maintain the `scope="step"`.

Comment: I don't think the problem is caused by step scope.  May be try to make a minimal job that can reproduce the problem and post it here?

Comment: I tried to remove the `late-binding` `scope="step"`, and the `rowNum` works again. Then I put it back, the `rowNum` keep display 0 in `System.out.println();`

Comment: Can you put your SQL query here? Do you have any where clause with values are changing in these scenarios.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The meaning of the Scope = "step" is that it create a instance for each step of execution which means that you will have a new instance for each thread.

So what should be happening is, once you define "step" scope, the map row is called by a new instance of your processor and it has the starting value 0. It is further indicated when you say that it works properly when you remove the step scope.

So what you can do is, keep a static atomic integer (Thread safe) and rely on that counter for your logic rather than relying on the rowNumber.

If this does not make sense, share your configuration for further analysis as well. Thanks.

Comment: O ya, why I never think about static. I keep declare normal integer and it cant work.

Comment: Always concern about the thread safety. Static variables are not thread safe so either look for synchronization or use an atomic variable like AtomicInteger.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to maintain `scope="step"` and want row counting don't use `RowMapper` `rowNum` property but let `myVO` object implements [`ItemCountAware`](http://docs.spring.io/spring-batch/trunk/apidocs/org/springframework/batch/item/ItemCountAware.html) and delegate to SB the responsibility to set the current item number.